# Unexpected regular expression groups

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to use regular expressions for analyzing a url, but I can't get the regex groups as I would expect them to be. 
My regular expression is:

```
@"member/filter(.*)(/.+)*"
```

The strings to match:

1. "member/filter-one"
2. "member/filter-two/option"
3. "member/filter-three/option/option"

I expect to get the following groups:

1. member/filter-one, /filter-one
2. member/filter-two/option, /filter-two, /option
3. member/filter-three/option/option, /filter-three, /option(with 2 captures)

I get the result for the first string, but fore the 2 others I get:

1. member/filter-two/option, /filter-two/option, empty string
2. member/filter-three/option/option, /filter-three/option/option, empty string

What can be the issue?

Comment: `(/.+)*` can cause a [ReDoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS). Better do: `(/[^/]+)*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
@"member/filter([^/]*)(/.+)*"
```

Another way could be to use the `MatchCollection` this way:

```
string url = "member/filter-three/option/option";
url = url.Replace("member/filter-", string.Empty); // cutting static content
MatchCollection matches = new Regex(@"([^/]+)/?").Matches(url);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Here, you first remove the constant part from your string (it could be a parameter of a function). Then you simply check for everything inside two `/` characters. You do that by identifying `[^/]` as the character you want to match, which means **match one character, that is not a `/`**, then put an identifier after that (+ sign), which means, **match more than one character**.

Comment: thanks for helping. can u explain a little please? what [^/] means? and what about the 'any-letter-sign' - (.)

Answer (score 0):

The "member/filter([^/]*)(/.+)*" seems logical but is impractical as it accepts empty options (i.e. member/filter1/////////). A more accurate-practical pattern which also allows you to accept more than one filter with options is **member(/filter[^/]+(/[^/]+)*)***